# Lsyncd 2.0.4 : excluding a file from syncing

Tags: lsyncd

I want to prevent my robots.txt file from syncing to the front end server.
Here is my /etc/lsyncd.conf file:

```
settings = {
        logfile    = "/tmp/lsyncd.log",
        statusFile = "/tmp/lsyncd.stat",
        statusInterval = 1,
}
sync{
        default.rsync,
        source="/var/www/html/blog",
        target="sync:/var/www/html/blog",
        rsyncOpts="-ltus",
        excludeFrom="/var/www/html/blog/robots.txt",
}
```

The /tmp/lsyncd.log tells

```
Normal: recursive startup rsync: /var/www/html/blog/ -> sync:/var/www/html/blog/ excluding
HELLO WORLD
Normal: Startup of '/var/www/html/blog/' finished.
Normal: Calling rsync with filter-list of new/modified files/dirs
/robots.txt
/
Normal: Finished a list = 0
```

This setup doesn't seems to work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the `excludeFrom` dir is relative to `source` dir; thus, `excludeFrom="/robots.txt"` might work.

**EDIT:** Oh my God, forget what I wrote above. `excludeFrom` is an rsync parameter which specifies a text file containing a list of files to be excluded, one file or pattern per line. So, your `excludeFrom` should contain a path to a file, which then contains this `/var/www/html/blog/robots.txt` or `/robots.txt`.

Comment: Didn't work `Error: Cannot open exclude file '/robots.txt': /robots.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: Whoops! See my edit.

Comment: This method completely solved my problem. You have provide the relative part according you have mentioned source path by `sync` settings option, `source`

Answer (score 1):

Use `rsync`'s `--exclude` directive in `lsyncd`'s config parameter `rsyncOpts`, or `_extra`, depending on the `lsyncd` version you use.

Answer (score 1):

per https://axkibe.github.io/lsyncd/manual/config/layer4/ :

> excludeFrom is FILENAME parameter, loads exclusion rules from this file, on rule per line

note that https://community.rackspace.com/general/f/34/t/3503 :

> CAUTION!  When using excludeFrom and a file, make sure the **file has no empty lines in it**. If it does, lsyncd treats this as "exclude /" and then everything gets excluded.